# Bond future's roll (and other rolls)

Tags: fixed-income, bond, bond-futures

I am missing some intuition on the above subject. Say I am long CTD basis (I.e. short futures):

1. I may opt to hold onto my position till last delivery for many reasons, say switch, wildcard etc. Why would I ever opt to make delivery though? At some point even if there is negligible optionality am I not nearly always better off closing my position ? (Assuming there is reasonable demand for the ctd outside delivering).
2. Now say, I am just outright short. I can either make delivery or roll my futures trades. To weigh up which is better I'd effectively compare:

A. My financing costs of buying ctd and delivering into the contract.
Vs.
B. Buying the roll.

Is this a legitimate comparison?

Basically, I think what I am missing is the linkage between rolls and financing. Or I may just be totally off piste.

Appreciate the help.

Comment: If you close out the future and sell the bond you have 2 transaction costs, if you go to delivery you don't. And with the delivery just a few days away the futures market is not very liquid, the active traders have switched to the new contract.

Comment: Assume this is answering part 1. If so, I agree. But..is that it? In fact if I am going to make a bond delivery because of the harsh exchange penalties on not delivering I would usually need the bonds in the box a couple of days before delivery anyway  therefore financing above gc..I would have thought that is very sizable relative to transaction costs (unless you're assuming the future is v illiquid as everyone has rolled to next contract)?

Comment: OK yes that's what I thought. Sorry its not letting me edit my comment now.

Comment: I'll state another problem which I have encountered. When the ctd in the next future is different from the current. Outside of delivering bid/offer widens materially.

Comment: I guess my part 2. Maybe a bit confusing or not well written. I'll try restate.. if I am short futures, how should I compare my option of either delivering or rolling. Ofcourse sometimes I may want to try buy the ctd to deliver, but will not be able to in which case I would have to roll. But outside of this friction..would my main consideration be the IRR of the roll versus the actual repo to the next delivery?